# Trigger Date for reruns

Tags: azure-data-factory

My pipelines activities need the date of the run as a parameter. Now I get the current date in the pipeline from the utcnow() function. Ideally this would be something I could enter dynamically in the trigger so I could rerun a failed day and the parameter would be set right, now a rerun would lead to my pipeline being rerun but with the date of today not the failed run date.

I am used to airflow where such things are pretty easy to do, including scheduling reruns. Probably I think too much in terms of airflow but I can't wrap my head around a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my problem I had to create a nested structure of pipelines, the top pipeline setting a variable for the date and then calling other pipelines passing that variable.
[image]

With this I still can't rerun the top pipeline but rerunning Execute Pipeline1/2/3 reruns them with the right variable set. It is still not perfect since the top pipeline run stays an error and it is difficult to keep track of what needs to be rerun, however it is a partial solution.

Answer (score 0):

- In ADF,it is not supported directly to pass trigger date at which pipeline got failed to trigger.
- You can get the trigger time using `@pipeline().TriggerTime` .
- This system variable will give the time at which the trigger triggers the pipeline to run.

[image]

- You can store this trigger value for every pipeline and use this as a parameter for the trigger which got failed and rerun the pipeline.

Reference: Microsoft document on [System Variables on ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables#pipeline-scope)

Comment: The problem with that is that trigger time does not contain the date, and the date is the only thing I am interested in.

Comment: I stored the value of `@pipeline().TriggerTime` in a variable. This contains date and time also. Refer this [img](https://i.imgur.com/PO6pQFo.png)

Comment: I am very confused as this never worked for me. Can you show the snippet you put in the set variable expression?

Comment: And for a rerun, the trigger time stays the original value or is it the new trigger time?

Comment: Can you show the snippet you put in the set variable expression?-- **Check this [Image link](https://imgur.com/8e5GxWg)**

Comment: And for a rerun, the trigger time stays the original value or is it the new trigger time? -- **Pipeline should be designed in a way to store the triggered time in some datastore, whenever the pipeline is failed. Later you can refer the triggered time data for rerun.**

Comment: I am not sure if I get it right, now I have a calendar based on outside factors, to decide when to run my pipeline. I have a daily pipeline checking that calendar. Each time this creates logs containing information over success and failure. You say additionally I need to store the failed runs date in a table somewhere? The rerun button is simply useless? I assume that I am using data factory completely wrong. Anyway my solution below works for me only that I don't get a clean table in monitoring which I would like to but I don't see how writing the dates down will help with that.